# Integrate website template in eclipse maven project

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, web

I was wondering if it's possible to integrate a free website template downloaded into an eclipse maven project developed using spring. (I talk about html, javascript, css files). And how to do it ? just copy all files in folders of the projects ?

Comment: Basically... yes. For example `WEB-INF/resources`. But be careful when specifying URL's to those files.

Comment: what about javascript resources ? it's the same thing even though eclipse is creating me a separate folder for those ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of directory structure:

```
webapp
     |
     resources
     |       |
     |       css (CSS files go here)
     |       |
     |       js (JavaScript files go here)
     |   
     |
     WEB-INF
           |
           views (JSP, html... files go here)
```

However a big note! As I mentioned, you have to be careful about loading them.

I.e. in JSP you load JS and CSS files like this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/style.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/functions.js" />"></script>
```

In something like Thymeleaf you will do it like this:

```
<link th:href="@{/resources/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

<script th:src="@{/resources/js/functions.js}"></script>
```

Basically, it depends which template engine you use.

Comment: so i couldn't make it work. the resources folder should be in let's say MyApp/resources ? or WebContent/resources ? i also took care while loading them from the jsp.

Comment: It can be both. But if you are using JSP, I guess it should go in WebContent/resources.

Comment: and how shall i reffer to the resource when including it in jsp ? still <c:url resources ? or directly folder name/res.css

Comment: i tried to access a css file in browser from my WebContent/resources/css/file.css and it appears that is not accesible. i get a 404

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
You can copy the folders. but you have to include in the build.xml to create the deployment file. 
should be in under WEB-INF/xyz..
dependent on your request url